# https issue in opencart

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, opencart

I have done secure security(https) in my website, if I open my website means it is showing like (http://www.kuberansilks.in/), but when I opened in browser it's automatically take https secure protocol, 
and the url look like (https://www.kuberansilks.in). So, how can I avoid this issue, please help me (I'm using AWS server).

My htaccess code below please check it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^kuberansilks\.in [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.kuberansilks.in/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/storage/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your ht-access file using below code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^kuberansilks\.in [NC]

//Added lines
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301] 


RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.kuberansilks.in/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/storage/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=off
RewriteRule ^/?(checkout|account|admin) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.co\.uk [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.site.co.uk/$1 [R,L]


config.php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://www.site.co.uk/');
// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.site.co.uk/');
define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'https://www.site.co.uk/image/');

/admin/config.php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://www.site.co.uk/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'https://www.site.co.uk/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.site.co.uk/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'https://www.site.co.uk/');
define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'https://www.site.co.uk/image/');
```

Please check It should work.